# how to push change in other branch which already commit on other branch

Tags: git, git-commit

I have two branches master and version_one.

I was in master branch and I have added few files in git and commited on master but I want to pust it on version_one branch

Can I change checkout branch version_one and push that commit on version_one so that my changes are push on version_one branch only

```
git branch
master

git add file_name.txt
git commit -m "new change"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. I am assuming that you already have version_branch in your local. 
One of the options which I follows is -

1. Checkout to the master branch. Revert the changes which you pushed to the master. You can do using

   ```
   git reset HEAD~
   ```

   By this you can see the changes under git status
2. Checkout to version branch. Before that, you need to stash the changes and apply the same stash after checkout.

   ```
   git stash
   git checkout version
   git stash apply
   ```
3. Then commit your changes.